# TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option

Tags: node.js

I get TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option when I push the app to Heroku, but the app work very well at local host.

I also install the dotenv and require it at the top of my code.

```js
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets",
    userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    console.log(profile);

    User.findOrCreate({
      googleId: profile.id
    }, function(err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

In my .env file, I sure I put CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET as well.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure your `.env` is NOT in git or other source control if you're using one. Secrets don't belong in source control.

Heroku calls environment variables [Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), so set `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` as config vars for your project on Heroku, and these will be accessible via `process.env` just like with `dotenv`.